# Translate of a geodesic that goes through a fixed point on $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, computational-geometry, geodesics, closed-geodesic

Consider the complex upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ with the hyperbolic geometry. Fix a point $z \in \mathbb{H}$ and also a geodesic $c$. I want to find a hyperbolic translation $\gamma c$ passes that through $z$, where $\gamma \in SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$. More specifically, in my case $z \in c$, but I want to find such a $\gamma c$ where $\gamma \notin Aut(c)$.

Is there any efficient algorithm or idea that could lead to an algorithm?

P.S:
My final goal is finding a concrete description of the projection of $c$ in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$. So I need to find the points on the boundary of the fundamental domain (bounded by $Re(w) = \pm 1/2$ and the unit semicircle centered at the origin) at which the projection of $c$ is incident. So suppose $c$ intersects $Re(w) = 1/2$ at $z$, now I want to find $\gamma z$ such that it passes through $z$. (it is clear that such a $\gamma$ exists). And then repeat this process with $c$ replaced with $\gamma z$ and $z$ replaced by the 2nd point of intersection of $\gamma z$ with boundary of the fundamental domain.

Comment: How are you representing $c$?

Comment: How do you know that a $\gamma \in SL(2, \mathbb Z)$ exists? $\mathbb Z$ means the integers, right?

Comment: @wlad Sorry for the confusion. In my situation, existence is known. My final goal is finding the projection of $c$ in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$. I'll add that to the original post.

Comment: There is also the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry, see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model. In that model the points and the lines have a natural interpretation and definite and indefinite binary quadratic forms, respectively. In that model your problem corresponds to the reduction of quadratic forms. There is a rich literature on that subject.